# Append onclick to all but one link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code

```js
function callback(e) {
    var e = window.e || e;

    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A')
        return;

    nanobar.go(100)
}

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
else
    document.attachEvent('onclick', callback);
```

It's appending onclick and nano bar appears when any link on page is clicked, so there's nice loading effect like on youtube. However there's one link which shouldn't trigger nanobar, how do I exclude it in this code?

Comment: just add some attribute to that link and check that attribute in the callback, if it matches then just ignore.

Comment: I can't see any jQuery here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already has an exclusion rule (in this case it's ignoring events from elements other than `<a>`), just add to that exclusion like so:

```
if (e.target.tagName !== 'A' || e.target.href.slice(-1) === "#") //exclude any hash anchors
  return;
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution, however I need to have a way to exclude "#" on every page in my domain i.e http://example/node/234#, because I have facebook style chat (iflychat) and that's its anchor.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to exclude all links that start with a hash symbol? If that's what you want then I've edited my answer to be correct. If there is a different pattern you are searching for, let me know and I can provide a regex solution.

Comment: Yes, very close, I need to exclude all links that end with hash symbol.

Comment: Easy enough, should be `e.target.href.slice(-1) === "#"`

Comment: dave There's one more thing, how to make it work only for internal links pointing to other pages of my site and exclude all the external links?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
<a href="#">test</a>
<a href="#">test</a>
<a id="noclick" href="#">test</a>
<a href="#">test</a>
<script>
    $( "a" ).not( "#noclick" ).click(function(){
      alert("clicked");
    });
</script>
```

---

demo
http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/aOzxza

Answer (score 0):

How do you define your link tags? Is there any way to include some class or attribute on the link tags? If there is, then you should add a specific class to those links which should trigger nanobar. Then just add the event listener for those which has that class. The link tags without that class won't have the nanobar function added.

Just wanted to tell you how it's done.

Comment: I want all links to trigger nanobar save for chat links which have class but I think it would be easier to just exclude address because they link to # like an anchor to the top of the page for instance.

Comment: That is an important factor to provide a valid solution to your problem. You should have mentioned that in your question. That's why I didn't provide any code, because I don't know the structure of your HTML. Would you like to update your question in order to include some more useful info?

Comment: dave provided solution only thing I need now is to regex match every link with # at the end..